# ssh connection refusing and .runinstaller pop up not coming

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, putty, oracle-12c

Facing one issue during two node RAC setup in Laptop.
.runinstaller at first showing the "DISPLAY CAN NOT SET ERROR". Then after sort this out by setting display it is not shwing any popup so that I can proceed to next step.

History :- Before reaching this step I was facing another issue with oracle linux gnome display. So from the boot screen, used the cntr+alt+tab and opened the gnome display with startx as root user. So basically running runinstaller in X terminal as I opened the gnome DISPLAY as STARTX.

```
runinstaller is stucked

./runInstaller
Starting Oracle Universal Installer...

Checking Temp space: must be greater than 415 MB.   Actual 11216 MB    Passed
Checking swap space: must be greater than 150 MB.   Actual 4479 MB    Passed
```

What I have tried:- I have tried lots of things to sort this out from last 24 hours.

1st thought:- Tried with the mobaxterm or putty through ssh. For that set the ssh port in linux as 22 in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config. Then disabled the firewalld in linux. appropriate changes also made in selinux. Putty is showing connection refused. I am pasting all my outputs below.

So basically I am facing two problems.
1> unable to launch .runinstaller. this is the main problem.To sort this out I am facing the below mentioned problem.
2> Unable to connect to linux from putty.
I am using virtual box and host is windows 10. from windows I can ping to 127.0.0.1 .

```
    sh example.com -X -v
output:-
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to example.com [93.184.216.34] port 22.

    ifconfig


output:-
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.56.71  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.56.255
        inet6 fe80::42ec:8d8f:412f:80b0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:ef:65:d8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 45  bytes 5400 (5.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.10.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.10.255
        inet6 fe80::4347:1d9c:1ea9:4d43  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:21:7a:89  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 45  bytes 5394 (5.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s9: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.4.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.4.255
        inet6 fe80::21eb:7039:c6d1:1145  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:c8:5a:c8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 107  bytes 125890 (122.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 115  bytes 11626 (11.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2115  bytes 208941 (204.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2115  bytes 208941 (204.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:ae:f2:f8  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Tried to connect to 127.0.0.1 through putty, but showing connection refused. port used 22.

```
    hostname -i

showing 192.168.56.71
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the question by myself only. Posting it for other peoples.

I have started the gnome display as root user with startx.

now check whether xclock is working.

it should work.

But in case of oracle or any other user it is not working

So my target is to enable the xclock for other user also because only oracle user can run the ./runinstaller.

in root try xhost +localhost

so from root just use su oracle.

Now again try xclock .

If it works then pop also will come for .runinstaller.

OUFFF!!! At Last..